# unable to see Undertow logs via SLF4J

Tags: java, undertow

I asked this question on the Undertow dev group, but received no response.

I wrote a sample test application using Java 17. I've used embedded Tomcat in the past, but I read high reviews for Undertow so I wanted to try it out. I don't need Java/Jakarta EE servlets; I just need to respond to requests using path templates.

I successfully started up an Undertow server and so far it's working as expected. But no logging. I see in `Undertow.start()` that I should see "starting server: …", but I don't.

```java
    public synchronized void start() {
        UndertowLogger.ROOT_LOGGER.infof("starting server: %s", Version.getFullVersionString());
```

I'm using `io.undertow:undertow-core:2.3.10.Final`. For logging I'm using SLF4J 2.0.9 and Logback 1.4.11. I have my Logback file configured to use `INFO` level logging:

```xml
<configuration>
  <root level="info">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

I even tried (after a bit of research) forcing JBoss Logging to use SLF4J before starting the server:

```java
System.setProperty("org.jboss.logging.provider", "slf4j");
```

Still no logs from Undertow

I stepped through the code. Undertow's `Slf4jLocationAwareLogger` is calling `LOG_METHOD.invoke(logger, null, className, Integer.valueOf(level), text, EMPTY, thrown)` where `level` has a value of `20`. Using reflection this invokes Logback's `Logger.filterAndLog_0_Or3Plus(final String localFQCN, final Marker marker, final Level level, final String msg, final Object[] params, final Throwable t)` method the `if (effectiveLevelInt > level.levelInt)` check fails because `effectiveLevelInt` is `10000` and `level.levelInt` is `20000`, so the method returns without logging (i.e. without calling `buildLoggingEventAndAppend(localFQCN, marker, level, msg, params, t)`).

First of all, why am I not getting any logs?

Secondly, why is Undertow invoking Logback directly? The whole point of SLF4J is to provide a general abstraction layer across loggers. How can I make Undertow invoke SLF4J directly? (In fact, the latest SLF4J allows system properties to specify an actual logging implementation; see [SLF4J-450](https://jira.qos.ch/browse/SLF4J-450). If Undertow is bypassing SLF4J and requires Logback, or tries to guess the logging implementation and access it directly, that defeats the whole purpose of SLF4J and will break.)

Undertow looks really promising, and it worked well enough for me to give a demo at a recent Java user group meeting. But I hope I can get Undertow logging working via SLF4J, as that is critical for any embedded server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it's worth, Undertow does not use SLF4J, it uses jboss-logging which is a facade similar SLF4J.

The issue is your `logback.xml` file. You need to define the `STDOUT` appender. Something like:

```xml
<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} -%kvp- %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Without defining the `STDOUT` appender there is not appender for the reference so nothing is logged.

Comment: You are right; adding a `STDOUT` appender to my Logback configuration file allowed me to start seeing Undertow logging. (I had thought that Logback provided a `STDOUT` appender by default; I'm supprised it provided no warning when none was defined.) However the fact that Undertow uses its own logging mechanism is probably going to be a dealbreaker. I see that [Jetty switched to SLF4J](https://github.com/jetty/jetty.project/issues/4572), so I'll probably switch to Jetty. Thanks for the helpful information.

Comment: It's just a logging facade. It will log to logback without a problem at all. It doesn't require any specific log manager.

Comment: "It's just a logging facade." More to the point, it's _another_ logging facade, different from the logging facade an overwhelming majority of applications use. I've never even heard of another non-JBoss application using the JBoss logging facade. What the world does not need is another logging facade. If JBoss wants to create its own logging facade but provide a way that its output can be directed to SLF4J, obeying _all_ of the SLF4J configurations, then that's fine—but that doesn't seem to be the case here.

Comment: FWIW it’s been around for decades. From my understanding it was created before SLF4J existed.